# Mayer-Vietoris sequence from a bicartesian square of commutative rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, local-cohomology

An article that I am reading quotes the following theorem (5.3 p.481, reformulated to focus on the commutative case) from **Algebraic K-Theory** by Hyman Bass:
Let $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A @>p_2>> A_2\\
@V p_1 V V @VV f_2 V\\
A_1 @>>f_1> A'
\end{CD}
be a cartesian square of commutative ring homomorphisms in which $f_1$ or $f_2$ is surjective. Then there is an exact Mayer-Vietoris sequence :
$$0 \rightarrow U(A) \rightarrow U(A_1) \oplus U(A_2) \rightarrow U(A') \rightarrow Pic(A) \rightarrow Pic(A_1) \oplus Pic(A_2) \rightarrow Pic(A')$$
where $U(.)$ is the group of units of a ring.
I need to understand this result better, but I don't know algebraic K-theory. Therefore I am trying to obtain this result using a Mayer-Vietoris sequence from local cohomology.

So far I have the following :
With the extra hypothesis that both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are surjective, then the above diagram is also cocartesian and $h_1$ and $h_2$ must also be surjective : the map $a_1 \otimes a_2 \mapsto f_1(a_1)f_2(a_2)$ is a canonical isomorphism from $A_1 \otimes_A A_2$ to $A'$. Taking the spectrum of the whole diagram yields a bicartesian diagram of affine schemes (using lemma [37.14.1](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0ET0) from the Stacks Project), where every map is a closed immersion.

Then, I would like to use exercise III.2.4 from Hartshorne, which states the following:
Let $Y_1,Y_2$ be two closed subsets of a topological space $X$, and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf of Abelian groups over $X$. Then there is a long exact sequence of cohomology with supports:
$$... \rightarrow H^i_{Y_1 \cap Y_2}(X,\mathcal{F}) \rightarrow H^i_{Y_1}(X,\mathcal{F}) \oplus H^i_{Y_2}(X,\mathcal{F}) \rightarrow H^i_{Y_1 \cup Y_2}(X,\mathcal{F}) \rightarrow H^{i+1}_{Y_1 \cap Y_2}(X,\mathcal{F}) \rightarrow ...$$

It looks like applying it and looking at the first terms of this long exact sequence might do but some pieces do not seem to fit easily.
I know that $X_1 = \text{Spec } A_1$ and $X_2 = \text{Spec } A_2$ can be seen as closed subschemes of $X = \text{Spec } A$, but then I am not sure that we will get $H_{X_1}^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X^\times) = H_0(X_1,\mathcal{O}_{X_1}^\times) = A_1^\times$ (or maybe $A_2^\times$ ?) and that the same result will hold for $H^1$, and it would also be needed that the local cohomology on the intersection $X_1 \cap X_2$ would agree with the cohomology on the scheme-theoretic intersection $X_1 \times_X X_2$. There is also the question of whether $X = X_1 \cup X_2$ and if not, is it possible to still recover

This all seems like it is too much to ask in general, but maybe in this particular case some of it is true? I would like to know whether this is already known before I keep digging.
Although I was hoping for a more general result, in the case I care about $A_1$ and $A_2$ are equal to each other and to a Dedekind domain, so these hypothesis can be added if necessary.